# How to contact AdMob support team regard an issue in finalized earnings

Tags: admob

Though it's not a technical question, but I had to ask here as I couldn't find an email address on AdMob to contact their support team.

I found this answer here, but it's not valid anymore as the Contact Us (Email) option doesn't exist anymore.

[How to contact Google Development Team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898549/how-to-contact-google-development-team)

---

As for my problem if anyone could enlighten me:

Last week I published 2 new apps, and I started to promote them, thankfully my earning started to increase (Not much, but still covers my promotion payment), and when I checked Transactions under AdMob Payment section, I got shocked as the revenue of last month (September) is 0$ though the estimated is about 100$ ... The only explanation (According to what I read) that AdMob took the spike of the revenue negatively and Zeroed whole September revenue.

---

**Update:**

I just found out that the report of September as follow

```
Sep 1 – 30, 2017

Invalid Traffic - AdMob Applications - AdWords Ads

−$0.03


Earnings - AdMob Applications - AdWords Ads

$109.37
```

**Yet October Starting balance is: $3.88 which is the same as September Starting balance.**

**So, why September ends with $113.22 & October starts with $3.88?**

---

**Update**

The problem got solved, and now it shows correct numbers.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [This](https://support.google.com/admob/gethelp) Wizard to open a ticket, in the box "Tell us what you need help with:" write what you want to search for (i.e earning) then press next, you can send email or chat with support team according to their availability.